# Understanding the code for the Google Maps API (Simple Maps), for implementing it into a website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
function initialize() {


var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I am trying to understand the javascript portion of this code under the script tag. What exactly is it doing, since the code is not commented out under the Google API.

Comment: It's initializing a map in the div with id map-canvas when the window load event is fired....what do you find confusing about the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has it all laid out pretty well: [Google Maps Javascript API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

```
var map;
```

Defines a variable named map.

```
function initialize() {..}
```

Defines function named intialize

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Sets up options for the map (zoom: how far the map is zoomed in on it's point. center: center of the map defined by latitude and longitude values passed. mapTypeID: the type of map you want the maps API to appear as (ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN, HYBRID)

Comment: no problem can you add the question as solved, i can deff use the rep thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

This is setting various options for the map; the zoom level of the map, the initial coordinates of the map and the type of map to use (you can use roadmap, satellite or hybrid)

```
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
 mapOptions);
```

This creates the map object and adds it to your page.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This attaches an event listener to the window so that when it loads up the initialise function will run thereby creating the map.